# Django force using cache on queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django queryset with slicing. I want to evaluate it once and then use the cached result.

This is the code:

```
items_filtered = Item.objects.filter(......)
items_filtered_sliced = items_filtered[:100]
items_filtered_sliced_updated = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=items_filtered_sliced).update(....)
```

I need to use the `items_filtered_sliced` queryset later to filter it, so in order to prevent filtering sliced queryset (which is not possible) I wanted to use the queryset first result and tried this -

```
items_filtered_sliced2 = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=items_filtered_sliced)
```

But seems like the `items_filtered_sliced` is evaluated again and returns the next 100 instead of returning the previous result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list(…)` to force evaluating the `QuerySet`. You can even do this only in the `pk__in`, and this will still force the `items_filtered_sliced` to get evaluated:

```
items_filtered = Item.objects.filter(…)
items_filtered_sliced = items_filtered[:100]
Item.objects.filter(pk__in=list(items_filtered_sliced)).update(…)
for item in items_filtered_sliced:
    # do something
    print(item)
```

This works because iterating, calculating the length, etc. all "consume" the `QuerySet`, and the `QuerySet` will store internally the records in a list.

This however will *not* use the cache if you perform extra filters, etc. So if you would use `for item in items_filtered_sliced.all():`, it would again make a new query to the database.

Comment: thanks. The point is that I need the result as queryset since I need to filter it later in a function that expects a queryset.

Comment: @user2880391: well then you can not cache it. Since Django does not know how those filters actually work. All `.filter(..)` does is translating it to an SQL query. So Django does not know how it would process a list of model objects with a filter. Note that `item_filtered_sliced` is a `QuerySet`, also after the `.update(..)`, but if you thus will further filter it, then you can not cache it.